# mail() function PHP failed sending to email

Tags: php, function, email

I have a mail function in my PHP file . When I excecute the file it doesn't give me any error messages but the email is not sent either. I have installed and started the Mercury Mail.

Here is my code:

```
$result = mysql_query("select email from user
                        where username='$username'");
$email = mysql_result($result, 0, "email");
$from = "another_emailgmail.com";
$mesg = "Your password have been changed";



if (mail($email, "Login information", $mesg, $from))
    return true;
```

I have looking in another similar post but it seems they have not installed Mercury Mail and they dont't have the same problem.

Comment: You don't need 'From: ' in your email address variable.

Comment: And quote the email :- `$email = 'some_email@gmail.com';`

Comment: Please gibe more debug information. What's the error message? What's in the logs? `/var/log/mail.err` for example, `/var/log/php5-fpm.log`,...

Comment: It seems that's not the problem.

Comment: It's not giving me any error messages , but I haven't received an email.

Comment: @Pirlo [enable PHP errors](http://blog.flowl.info/2013/enable-display-php-errors/) and look into the log files in.

Comment: It's not an answer but *cough* http://phpmailer.worxware.com/ *cough* - So much more control over everything. Give it a shot.

Comment: The interesting thing is that the mysql_query is changing the data in the data base but I don't recieve any message about the change.

Comment: DanFromGermany
I put that in my PHP file and it still not showing the error messages.

Answer (score 0):

This code works out-the-box (change your e-mail address!). `mail()` function return a bool value, then if it returns TRUE you have to check your system log and system e-mail spool looking for routing errors or something similar.

```
<?php
if(mail('some_email@gmail.com','E-mail subject',"E-mail body\r\n")){
  echo 'Works'."\n";
}else{
  echo 'Failed'."\n";
}
```

Comment: It gives me "Works" but I still don't recieve any message.

Comment: Yes, it's correct. Your problem is NOT on PHP side, but deep on your SMTP software. PHP just delegate sending to your SMTP, aka PHP do NOT send any e-mail directly. You have to look your SMTP logs to looking for errors.

Answer (score 0):

```
mail($mailto, $subject,stripslashes($message), $headers);
```

Headers Can be set as below

```
        $headers .= 'From:from@gmail.com' . "\r\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.changes the fields according to your needs.just change the data according to your need

```
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers .= "To: $mydata->name <$mydata->email>" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "From: demo.com <contact@demo.com>" . "\r\n";

mail($mydata->email, $subject, $message, $headers);
```